# Android Studio ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, android-studio

I am new to Android Development and creating a project that contains a database with 2 tables.

```
public class DbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final String DATABSE_NAME = "ExpenseManagerDB";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String TABLE_PEOPLE = "people";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_TP = "tp";

public static final String TABLE_TRANSACTIONS = "transactions";
public static final String COLUMN_TID = "tid";
public static final String COLUMN_PID = "pid";
public static final String COLUMN_DESC = "desc";
public static final String COLUMN_AMOUNT = "amount";
public static final String COLUMN_DT = "dt";

private static final String TABLE_CREATE_PEOPLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PEOPLE + " (" +
        COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_TP + " TEXT )";

private static final String TABLE_CREATE_TRANSACTIONS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TRANSACTIONS + " (" +
        COLUMN_TID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        COLUMN_PID + " INTEGER, " +
        COLUMN_DESC + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_AMOUNT + " INTEGER "+
        COLUMN_DT + " TEXT )";

public DbOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABSE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE_PEOPLE);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE_TRANSACTIONS);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PEOPLE);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TRANSACTIONS);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}
```

I have created a ListView and I want to show the names from the people table and total amount of money from the transaction table for each user. I know how to do that.
After that I want to click on a certain name in the list and direct it to another activity where I can enter transactions for only that user, which means I have to carry the id of that item in the listView to the new activity.
What is the bestway to do that. Simply saying I want to understand how to get the data in the table that is related to the name in the list(name can be duplicated, only the is is a primary key).
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned you should create an `AdapterView` using the objects you got from table. So that when you click on any item you are able to get that object, then you can use the name, id whatever. After that, you can serialize that object and send it to the activity.